# ant error: diamond operator is not supported

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to build JLaTeXMath-android, which can be found [here](https://github.com/lokedhs/jlatexmath-android). However when I run `ant` I get

```
D:\android studio\jlatexmath-android-master>ant
Buildfile: D:\android studio\jlatexmath-android-master\build.xml

init:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 147 source files to D:\android studio\jlatexmath-android-m
aster\bin
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with
-source 1.5
    [javac] D:\android studio\jlatexmath-android-master\src\org\scilab\forge\jla
texmath\ArrayOfAtoms.java:40: error: diamond operator is not supported in -sourc
e 1.5
    [javac]     array = new LinkedList<>();
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
    [javac] D:\android studio\jlatexmath-android-master\src\org\scilab\forge\jla
texmath\Box.java:106: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
    [javac]     protected LinkedList<Box> children = new LinkedList<>();
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
    [javac] 2 errors
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
D:\android studio\jlatexmath-android-master\build.xml:88: Compile failed; see th
e compiler error output for details.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I also tried `ant -Djava.source=7 -Djava.target=7` with the same result. any ideas?

edit: after reading the first suggestion here, i tried `-antDjava_verion=1.7`, since that is the value which is put into source and target all the time. Output exceeds the limit of charaters here, so i uploaded it: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11663609/out.txt.html

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Specify the `source` and `target` attributes on the `javac` task in your build.xml:

```xml
<javac source="1.7"
       target="1.7"
       ... other attributes
```

Use 1.7 or 1.8 if you are using Java 8.

Comment: where do i have to put that? can you please view the xml file from the link i gave and tell me the line?

Comment: There appear to be lots of `javac` tasks in that file, you probably need to change them all to be safe.